# Handle empty query in Play Framework 2.1.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a search function in a Play 2.1.4 project that routes to /search/:query.

How would I go about in handling a situation where a user searches without adding a query?
Optional parameters are gone since Play 2.1, and I do not believe using a different route for it is a pretty solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually what's wrong about two routes? From logical point of view these are two separate actions: route with param should initialize the search process, while empty one should show empty search form or do some redirect.

```
GET     /search/:term   controllers.Application.search(term: String)
GET     /search         controllers.Application.blankSearch
```

Optionaly you can use a route with default value (ie. empty String) which is clean approach as common HTML form will send the request in exactly required format:

```
GET     /search         controllers.Application.search(q: String ?= "")
```

(request: `http://domain.loc/search?q=Looking+for+something`)

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I guess I will go for separate routes!

Comment: Just tip: first solution will be harder to handle within common HTML form, most probably you will need to use jQuery to build proper url, while second one will allow you to send request just by placing input field with `name="q"` in the GET form.

Comment: I just realized that I probably explained the situation badly, and you misunderstood it.. I use a form that posts to /search/performsearch, which then reroutes to get /search/:query with the query from searchForm.bindFromRequest().